# Fast search in collection type column

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Create collection type:

```
CREATE TYPE nums_list AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

Create table with column of collection type (nested table column):

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
        num NUMBER,
        tagged nums_list
)
NESTED TABLE tagged STORE AS mytest_tagged_table;
```

Insert 1 Million rows in table:

```
DECLARE 
    tagg_value nums_list := nums_list(3,4,5);
BEGIN
    for i in 1..1000000 loop
          if i = 600000 then
              tagg_value := nums_list(7,8);
          end if;

          INSERT INTO test1
          (num, tagged)
          VALUES
          (i, tagg_value);
    end loop;
END;
```

Then run query for searching element in collection type:

```
    select count(*) from test1 where 8 member of tagged;
```

This query runs slowly, approximately 7-8 seconds is execution time.

Question: how to speed up of execution time? may be indexes? but how to use indexes for nested table column I don't get.

P.S. I tried use looping an checking every row in PL/SQL block, using  cursor and then return result as pipelined table function, but this was more slowly than direct query.

Comment: As you've written your example, I think all rows from 600,000 on will have the number 8 in the list.  That means, your query will return 400,000 (out of 1,000,000 rows).  Nested table or not, that's not the type of query an index will help much with.  Was that your intention in the example, to have so many rows satisfying the query?

Comment: @Matthew -- Yes exactly 400,001 rows  returns this query. Is this so big  data ?

Comment: It's not that it's "big", per se.  It is that it is a large percentage of the total number of rows in the table.  In such situations, it is more efficient to read the entire table (i.e., "full table scan") to perform the search, rather than 400,000 index lookups.  A full scan can read many table blocks in a single I/O, whereas an index lookup will take 3-4 I/Os _per row_.  With such a narrow table as this, a full table scan might need less than 100,000 I/Os (rough guess), whereas a nested loop join with an index might require over a million I/Os.

Comment: Is there some reason that you need to store a collection?  In general, it's going to be much more conventional to store this as a child table which then has many, many more options for performance tuning.

Comment: @JustinCave -- The only reason was that I have row (item), which may tagged by 10 different tags, so if store these in child table, there will be 10 rows for  each item (10 row for each tag for this item).  In collection case, there is only one row for single item, but you are right, another table seems  better. Also, from  Matthew's answer,  anyway "unnesting" of collections happened

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you perform an `EXPLAIN PLAN` on this query from your example:

```
select count(*) from test1 where 8 member of tagged;
```

... you will see that Oracle probably *is* using a (system-generated) index on `mytest_tagged_table` to help the performance.  The reason it still takes so long is that 400,000 index lookups is actually *less* efficient than just reading the whole table.

So, the question isn't "how can I get Oracle to use an index with my nested table"?  It's how can I get Oracle *not* to?

One alternative you have, since your `tagged` lists seem small, is to use a `VARRAY`.  These can be stored inline for better performance, although the associated syntax isn't as clean.

Here is your example, modified for `VARRAY`:

```
CREATE NONEDITIONABLE TYPE nums_varray AS VARRAY(10) OF NUMBER;

CREATE TABLE test2 (
        num NUMBER,
        tagged nums_varray
);

INSERT INTO test2
SELECT rownum,
       case when rownum < 600000 then new nums_varray(3,4,5) else new nums_varray(7,8) end
FROM   dual
connect by rownum <= 1000000;


select count(*) from test2 
where exists ( 
   SELECT '8 in list' 
   FROM TABLE(tagged) 
   WHERE column_value = 8);
```

On my system, this required only 3,600 buffer gets to run -- as opposed to the 2.1 *million* buffer gets that your example query required.  Correspondingly, it also runs much faster.

`VARRAYS` are not a direct equivalent to nested tables and they come with caveats.  But, based on your example, they may be what you are looking for.